# Winzip error / timestamp in file name related?

Tags: windows, gzip, winzip

I receive an error when attempting to use winzip to extract a .zip file.  The filename contains a colon character (used in the timestamp).  Is this something that winzip does not handle?
Also, the file has the extension ".tar.gz".  Is it permissible to use winzip to extract or will I have to use gunzip?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Winzip](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/254) supports tar gz compressed files.  You may have to rename it to .tgz though, not sure if it uses the "magic number" or the file extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinZip does not handle `:` in file names simply because it's not an allowed character in file names on Windows.

It's both used in disk names (`C:\`) and to separate an alternate file stream from the file name (`olle:kalle` is an alternate file stream `kalle` in the file `olle`)

See the [Wikipedia page on file name restrictions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words) for more details.